Prisma raw query integration with PostgreSQL full-text search: ts_rank and to_tsquery not working
I'm working with a PostgreSQL database, and I'm trying to convert a complex SQL query using Prisma's queryRaw. The query works fine using pg and pool.query, but when I attempt to use Prisma's $queryRaw, I'm running into issues.
Here's my working raw SQL query:
 const response = await pool.query(
      `SELECT *, ts_rank(document_with_idx, to_tsquery('simple', $1 || ':*')) AS rank FROM public."Celeb" WHERE document_with_idx @@ to_tsquery('simple', $1 || ':*') ORDER BY CASE WHEN lower(substring(displayname from 1 for 1)) = lower($1) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, CASE WHEN lower(substring(displayname from 1 for 1)) = lower($1) THEN substring(displayname from 3) END, rank DESC`,
      [name]
    );

This query uses PostgreSQL's full-text search functions to_tsquery and ts_rank, and works perfectly with pg.
However, when I try to run it with Prisma's queryRaw, it fails. Here's the Prisma code I've tried:
 const response = await prisma.$queryRaw`
      SELECT *, 
        ts_rank(document_with_idx, to_tsquery('simple', ${name} || ':*')) AS rank 
      FROM public."Celeb" 
      WHERE document_with_idx @@ to_tsquery('simple', ${name} || ':*') 
      ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN lower(substring(displayname from 1 for 1)) = lower(${name}) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, 
        CASE WHEN lower(substring(displayname from 1 for 1)) = lower(${name}) THEN substring(displayname from 3) END, 
        rank DESC
    `;

error: Raw query failed. Code: N/A. Message: Failed to deserialize column of type 'tsvector'.

Did you find a solution?
